# Multi-Class to Multi-Label Transformation in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to transform a Data set of labels to a binary representation via a SQL query, i.e. the following table:

```
|---------------------------|
| Example   | Label         |
|---------------------------|
|   1       |   Health      |
|   1       |   Business    |
|   1       |   Science     |
|   2       |   Sports      |
|   2       |   Business    |
|---------------------------|
```

Transforms into a new table:

```
|---------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Example   | Business      |   Health  |   Science |   Sports  |
|---------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1       |       1       |       1   |       1   |       0   |
|   2       |       1       |       0   |       0   |       1   |
|-----------|---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

via some SQL query. What would be said SQL query?

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please remove images and type you data structure, data sample and expected results. Also, type what have you tried so far. And finally, what DBRMS is this question related to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select example, sum(case when label='Business' then 1 else 0 end) 'Business'
  ,sum(case when label='Health' then 1 else 0 end) 'Health'
  ,sum(case when label='Science' then 1 else 0 end) 'Science'
  ,sum(case when label='Sports' then 1 else 0 end) 'Sports'
From MyTable
group by example
```

Comment: Thank you, Horaciux. I'm new to SQL, thus as to why you don't see my attempt. I tried putting in a table, but Stack Overflow would interpret the table as some syntax and change the output question to something not looking like a table. This is why you see the pictures rather than a text version of the table. I really appreciate the help. If I have further problems, I'll edit this question with what you have requested. Thank you again!